# AWS CDK Deploying to stage without deleting previous stages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm using AWS CDK to manage deployments of my API Gateway. I use stages to promote my code through environments, e.g. DEV, TEST, PREPROD, PROD. My script looks something like this:

```
export class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const api = new apigateway.SpecRestApi(this, 'my-api', {
      deploy: false,
      apiDefinition: apigateway.ApiDefinition.fromAsset('path/to/swagger.yaml'),
    });

    const stageName = this.node.tryGetContext('stageName');

    const deployment = new apigateway.Deployment(this, `my-api-deployment-${stageName}`, { api });
    new apigateway.Stage(this, `my-api-stage-${stageName}`, {
        stageName,
        deployment,
    });
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I promote my code from one stage to the next, e.g. `cdk deploy --context stageName=PREPROD`, previous stages are deleted, so I only end up with a single stage in my API Gateway.

Is it possible to deploy to a stage without deleting the other stages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are deploying same stack and `id` of deployment and stage is changing for different stageName parameter. Cloudformation will delete the previous resource and create a new one.

You need split your code into 2 stacks to make it work properly.
Stack 1 will be having code to create api and export it as

```
export class MyStack1 extends cdk.Stack {
  public readonly api: apigateway.SpecRestApi;
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    this.api = new apigateway.SpecRestApi(this, 'my-api', {
      deploy: false,
      apiDefinition: apigateway.ApiDefinition.fromAsset('path/to/swagger.yaml'),
    });
```

MyStack2 will be having code to create stage and deployment.

In you bin/App file you need to pass api from MyStack1 to MyStack2 constructor.

```
export class MyStack2 extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, api: apigateway.SpecRestApi, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

   const stageName = this.node.tryGetContext('stageName');

    const deployment = new apigateway.Deployment(this, `my-api-deployment`, { api });
    new apigateway.Stage(this, `my-api-stage`, {
        stageName,
        deployment,
    });
```

Keep the MyStack2 `id` like `my-api-deployment-stack-${stageName}`.

What this will do is you will have a common stack with api gateway and different stack per env like dev,test, preprod and prod.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I notice:

- If you change the second parameter which is logical name of the resource in Cloudformation, it will always delete and recreate.
- if we need two stages to be there, we must have two different physical resources, we can't have just one and keep changing the name, it will delete and recreate it.
- Deployment to a stage is not controlled by stage, but actual Deployment. So, keep the stage resource name static but only Deployment to be Dynamic, truly dynamic not stageName.

So, in short, we need two stages, two deployments and control which one to deploy based on dynamic logical name.
Code will look something like this:

Here is the full code:

```
const myRestApi = new apigateway.RestApi(this, "rest-api", {
  deploy: false,
});
const methods = myRestApi.root.addMethod(
  "ANY",
  new apigw.MockIntegration()
);

const StageOneDeploy = this.node.tryGetContext("StageOneDeploy");
const stageOneDeployment = new apigateway.Deployment(
  this,
  `api-deployment-${StageOneDeploy}`,
  {
    api: myRestApi,
  }
);

stageOneDeployment._addMethodDependency(methods);

new apigateway.Stage(this, `stageOne`, {
  stageName: "stageOne",
  deployment: stageOneDeployment,
});

const StageTwoDeploy = this.node.tryGetContext("StageTwoDeploy");
const stageTwoDeployment = new apigateway.Deployment(
  this,
  `api-deployment-${StageTwoDeploy}`,
  {
    api: myRestApi,
  }
);
stageTwoDeployment._addMethodDependency(methods);
new apigateway.Stage(this, `stageTwo`, {
  stageName: "stageTwo",
  deployment: stageTwoDeployment,
});
```

and to Deploy , we can change to a random number to which ever stage to deploy to.

```
cdk deploy HelloCdkStack --context StageOneDeploy=123456 --context StageTwoDeploy=9493812
```

Comment: Ok, so what if I wanted to keep StageOne static with the previous Deployment I assigned and create one new Deployment only for StageTwo, keeping both states?

Comment: is there a way to get rid of the _stage_ segment from `<url>/<stage>` in the stageTwo? For instance, I don't want the production stage to use segment "prod" but I'd like to keep it for "dev"